# Hermann OF the Teutonic Order VS Hermann FROM the Teutonic Order?

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is correct? I don't know which preposition is used in such case - from or of.

Comment: They are phrases, not sentences. If you are identifying Hermann as a member of the Order, you would use _of_. You might use _from_ if he had been sent somewhere as a representative of the Order.

Comment: helpful thank you